# How do i get an element from List<T> elements= new ArrayList<>();?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, icomparable

I want to get the elements from the list. 
I'm working right now on a project, next to the Class name is: 
`<T extends Comparable<T>>` written.

And I do have a ArrayList `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();`

But how do I get an element out of the List?
I tried `list.get(1);`  but then I get a Error: `error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to int`

Comment: You get the element exactly as you have written, but you must understand that the object you get is of type `T`, and not try to assign it to an `int` variable.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare

```
List<int> list = ...
```

but you can safely declare

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

`Integer` class matches the required signature (it implements `Comparable<Integer>`).

So when you do this, it's okay to do

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
list.add(13) // autoboxing converts int to Integer
int value = list.get(0) // autoboxing converts Integer back to int
```

As an extra note, please remember that it's possible to add `null`-s to that list, so the following will explode with NPE:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
list.add(null) // null reference is okay
int value = list.get(0) // throws, we got null Integer reference,
                        // that cannot be converted to a primitive
```

If you ever have a need to do this, you can do:

```
Integer value = list.get(0)
if (null != value) {
  int primitive = value // safe, because non-null
}
```